# NPE on constructor and superclass

Tags: kotlin

I have the following code:

```
public class CurrentPlayer(override val game: PewGame, spriteSheet: String) : Player(game, spriteSheet)
```

The hierarchy is as follows:
CurrentPlayer -> class Player -> trait MovingEntity -> trait Entity.

The trait 'Entity' has a field 'val game: PewGame'.
The constructor for Player looks like this:

```
public open class Player(override val game: PewGame, spriteSheet: String) : MovingEntity, InputAdapter()
```

In the constructor of Player, if you can call it that in kotlin, I have this:

```
this.sprite = CharacterSpriteSheet(Utilities.createTextureFromFile(spriteSheet), this.game.getSpriteBatch(), 0.25f)
```

Problem is, 'this.game' is null, therefore 'this.game.getSpriteBatch()' throws a NPE. I can't explain this in a better way, so any help is appreciated. To be more precise, after using a debugger:

I can see both `game` and `this` in the Player class. `game` is not null, but `this.game` is null for some inexplicable reason.

Thanks for helping!

EDIT: I forgot to mention that the issue is only present when I instantiate CurrentPlayer, and doesn't happen when I instantiate Player.

Comment: Can you paste all your code including the parent classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you store the same data in two fields: you override `game` in `Player` and then again in `CurrentPlayer`, which makes the same data stored twice. Incidentally, it makes the getter for the `game` property access an uninitialized field in `CurrentPlayer` instead of an initialized one in `Player`.

To fix this problem, just remove `override val` from `CurrentPlayer` declaration:

```
public class CurrentPlayer(game: PewGame, spriteSheet: String) : Player(game, spriteSheet)
```